# jQuery history and variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

I want to use the history.js plugin from jQuery. The code is:

```
// Global
var History = window.History;
$(document).ready(function() {
  History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(){
    console.log('Yeeeeeeaah!');
  });
  window.History.pushState(null, null, '#42');  // Yeeeeeeaah!
});
function anotherFunc() {
  window.History.pushState(null, null, '#test');  // Nothing happens
}
```

What's wrong with the scope?

Comment: hm I'm not sure about this plug-in, but usually the event is call 'popstate'

Comment: when do you call that anotherFunc()? Is it after the History.Adapter.bind is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not execute `anotherFunc`.

Nothing is wrong with the scope, but you could've omitted the `var History = window.History` and just used `History`.